# CodeIgniter, display MySQL query from Model to View, best practice

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have standart app which Controller get from Model only 1 row :

```
return $query->row();
```

, after that set variables (Array) and return data to some View:

```
    $data['fname'] = $user->fname;
    $data['lname'] = $user->lname;
    $this->load->view('someView', $data);
```

, then I get it from the View:

```
<?php echo $fname ; ?>
<?php echo $lname ; ?>
```

The problem is this, there can be or cannot be result from database. And if there isn't result I get an error:

> Message: Trying to get property of non-object

I fix that when I change the code in the Controller:

```
        $data['fname'] = $user['fname'];
        $data['lname'] = $user['lname'];
```

But if I do that and there is result from Database table, I see this error:

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

How to fix this ?
What is the best practice in situations like this?
I must add logic in the Model to return some properties which will be set for the example to NULL, if there is no row in database table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do:

```
return $query->row_array();
$data['user'] = $user;
```

And pass it ALL to the view?  Then you can determine when to echo in the view:

```
<!-- in view -->
<?= isset($user['fname']) ? $user['fname'] : 'No First Name Found';?>
```

Comment: This is another solution, too. But in this way I must add logic in the View, right ?

Comment: Presentation logic is generally considered to be ok I think

Comment: With return $query->row_array();  I don't need to check is it set or not, just it is NULL if the query is empty.

Answer (score 0):

how are you...?
Reading your concern, I think the best thing to do is that the model realizes a condition if the object that you bring as a result contains data ... if so assigns a variable from the model called "results_ok" and according to call that different views in the same view or perform condition with variable "results_ok" and displays the content you want ...

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the result from the database is different from `null`.

```
if($user != null)
{
    $data['fname'] = $user->fname;
    $data['lname'] = $user->lname;
}
```

The first error you get is because you are trying to access property of `null` which doesn't make sense. The second error you get is because you are trying to access object properties as if it is an array which in your case clearly isn't.

Comment: He will still have the  issue if either `fname` or `lname` is undefined.

Comment: If it exists as a field in the database it will be defined. Maybe empty, but defined. I guess he knows what fields he has in the database. The point of the whole thing is to recognize if the database returned anything.

Comment: But you are checking if the object `$user` is null, assuming his query returns at least one field `fname` for example, then your code will attempt to assign undefined properties. The alternative would be to check each field i.e `if(! isset($user->fname)` etc...

Comment: This 1 is almost the solution, because I need to do that for all my Models and I have another tables. The problem is that I don't know exists or not in the table. It is like site, where you can add info "about me" or you don't want to add it. Another solution is to add rows for each table with empty fields by default, but there are too many tables. There must be standart solution for this case.

Comment: If `$user` is different from `null` and if the table from which he reads data has a column called `fname` then he won't be accessing (not assigning as you said) undefined properties. Again I say, he knows what properties the `$user` object will have based on his database. Edit: you can check if a property exists with `property_exists` function

Answer (score 0):

You may consider incorporating a **$displayName** variable that will serve as a placeholder to inform the user if their complete name is not provided. We can also accept first name only as a minimum for display purposes.

```
$data['fname'] = is_object($user) ? $user->fname : 'User';
$data['lname'] = is_object($user) ? $user->lname : '';
$data['displayName'] =  ($data['fname'] != '' && $data['lname'] != '') ? $data['fname'] . $data['lname'] : '(Enter your name)'; 
$this->load->view('someView', $data);
```

- Default **$firstName** to "User" if not provided.
- Also add some error handling to prevent non-object errors.

Different aspects of your CodeIgniter views may want to use **$firstName** while in a headline or message you can use the **$displayName** with out having to concatenate the variables each time in the view or worry that it's missing.

Although when your user data is not properly completed it would be ideal to throw an official alert message within the UI as opposed to relying on $displayName. Rendering a completely different view is also another sensible option especially if a significant amount of user $data that the view relies on is missing.